# Access metadata for linked tables with excel

Tags: ms-access, metadata, linked-tables

I was able to find some code online and tweak a little to get the following (example) metadata details from Access database. The only restriction in my VBA code is table name not like "MSYS" or "~". However the metadata is not showing up for "**tables linked to MS excel**".

[image]

The above list is showing all tables metadata except the tables linked to Excel. Is there a code that can do this?

I am using the below code to obtain the above

Private

```
Sub ShowTableFields()

Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim x As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
   If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" AND Left(tdf.Name, 1) <> "~" Then ' Don't enumerate the system tables
      For x = 0 To tdf.Fields.Count - 1
      Debug.Print tdf.Name & "','" & tdf.Fields(x).Name "','" & tdf.Fields(x).Type
      Next x
   End If
Next tdf
End Sub
```

And then a case function to convert the Type to a description, didn't feel that relevant to add here.

Comment: Interesting, I just tested your code and my linked Excel is included in the output.

Comment: Oh is it? I am thinking it might be that my network drive access issue. I cant open the excel as it is not finding the drive on which the files are located. Just curious, on your linked excel are the data types just text and numbers? Or are they blank

Comment: My Excel has only text type data, output shows type 10.

Comment: thanks! Are those linked excels stored in your computer or are you accessing it from shared drive? I may not have access to my linked excesl due to restricted permission. How do I achieve linked excel metadata in the output? Kindly suggest.

Comment: All files are on my laptop. How can you have a link if you cannot access file? Can you copy file to computer?